# How to initialize bool with a logical expression?

Tags: php

```
$variable = (0 > 0)
```

For some reason, when I try to print $variable, it doesn't print anything. No null, nothing. But

```
$variable = (1 > 0)
```

sets $variable to true. Why is that, and what is the best way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$variable` is being set correctly -- you can see this with `var_dump($variable)`.

The issue is that in PHP trying to straight print `false` and `null` values prints the empty string, so nothing appears to happen. `var_dump` is one of the ways to check what's really going on; when dealing with booleans, a more convenient way is to cast to `int` first:

```
echo (int)$variable; // prints "0" or "1"
```

Comment: May be that will be more brief if add an explanation about printing null's and false values (i.e. because they are casted to string when output, therefore equivalent to `''`).

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Sorry, I didn't get this at all.

Answer (score 5):

`$variable = (0 > 0)` will `return false` and it will not display on screen

You can use [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for this like

```
$variable = (0 > 0);
var_dump($variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually printing a null string hence nothing is getting displayed there,
try printing something like !$variable and you'll see the change